# CA Rally - Import Test case

Tags: rally, ca

I could able to import test cases to rally from Excel with the below mentioned columns in Excel:
Project,Work Product,Name,Description,Method,Type,Owner

Tagging is one way teams can identify work items as part of feature initiatives or projects that may span multiple timeboxes.

How to add this Tag attribute in Excel sheet and import the test case to Rally?

Answer (score 0):

Use the CA Agile Central Add-In for Excel for importing and exporting. It supports tags too. Here's the [link](https://help.rallydev.com/rally-add-excel-installation-user-guide)

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge this is not supported with a direct import.. The method above with the plugin is ok but only if you are on Windows (bahhh) as there is no Linux/OSx version.

This has just gone or is continuing to go through a major rework as demo'd to me last month by the AC Product Owner of this feature.. I'll raise the question and get back to you...

I know you can now add the steps of a test case within the same import and link them, but that doesn't help;)

[Here's a link to the new functionality](https://help.rallydev.com/labs-new-import-syntax)

Comment: This function is now live and ready for all to use, can you have a look and mark as answered if this works for you.. Cheers!